# how to keep all urls in one class and access in required classess in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

i have created a class for example "allAPI.js"
inside of it

```
export default class allAPI extends Component {

BASE_URL: 'http://xx:xx:xx:xx/8080/api/app/"

Login:BASE_URL+ '/login';
Homepage: BASE_URL + '/home'
}
```

how to keep all urls at one place and access these urls to their required pages where there url is called.?

Comment: thing is i am looking to use constants in react native and call these constants in other pages example LOGIN_URL = "http://xxxx" in allapi.js and same calling in login.js class as callLoginApi(user)
{
    fetch('LOGIN_URL ', {  
  method: 'POST',

Answer (score 1):

Build a Global.js

```
module.exports = {
  BASE_URL: 'http://google.com',
  COLOR_TEXT: 'blue',
  //etc
};
```

On your main you just need to

```
GLOBAL = require('./globals');
```

and then to use the Links :

```
<View><Text>{GLOBAL.BASE_URL}</Text></View>
```

Comment: tried like method first but not able to import GLOBAL = require('./globals'); so i go with @dragas method. Thanks a ton by the way. :)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there are many ways to do it. You could go around it by defining a class and putting all the variables that correspond to particular endpoints. You could define particular endpoints in contexts where they make sense, etc.

Since ReactNative does not have a definition of `base URL`, all the URLs there will have to be absolute. The problem with this approach is that your endpoints will be variables, meaning that due to an error in your code, you could rewrite them at run time.

Sadly, javascript does not support `const` fields in classes by default, but there is a workaround for that. Personally I used this snippet to build my endpoint class:

```
export default function constantMaker(clazz, variable, value, writable = false, enumerable = true, configurable = false)
{
    Object.defineProperty(clazz, variable, {
        value: value,
        writable: writable,
        enumerable: enumerable,
        configurable: configurable
    });
}
```

And then called it like so:

```
import makeConstant from "./modules/helper/constant-maker.js";
export default class Constant {

}

makeConstant(Constant, "baseHTTP", "https:");
makeConstant(Constant, "baseUrl", Constant.baseHTTP + "//website.com");
makeConstant(Constant, "apiEndpoint", Constant.baseUrl + "/app/");
makeConstant(Constant, "newsUrl", Constant.apiEndpoint + "news/");
makeConstant(Constant, "clubsUrl", Constant.apiEndpoint + "clubs/");
makeConstant(Constant, "timetableUrl", Constant.apiEndpoint + "workout/timetable/");
```

After importing `constant.js` your endpoints will be available as fields in that class.

Comment: this is the best way i found but i dont getit whats clazz and other variables used for? thanks a ton :)

Comment: clazz is the Class where you write the constants, meanwhile other variables configure whether or not that particular field can be written to, enumerated or configured.